# How to retrieve images from firebase database for a particular user in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

This is the structure of my database:
[database structure, click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IieGD.png)

This is the JSON Tree:

```
    {
  "Images": {
"01": {
  "description": "Best Thing",
  "link": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/build3-9b01e.appspot.com/o/25018141_523451678022824_7360286065040556032_n.jpg?alt=media&token=8829f210-93d3-4f10-8a82-4a523209c4e9",
  "userId": "riazosama"
},
"02": {
  "description": "Best Thing",
  "link": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/build3-9b01e.appspot.com/o/25016768_1405603549550272_1874226094777827328_n.jpg?alt=media&token=8622ab00-6bad-4f69-b01e-21eb2202e9d7",
  "userId": "riazosama"
},
"03": {
  "description": "Best Thing",
  "link": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/build3-9b01e.appspot.com/o/25012591_1984569698483940_6077994085279334400_n.jpg?alt=media&token=1beeac3e-3a68-448b-845a-ae950e98b09a",
  "userId": "riazosama"
},
"04": {
  "description": "Best Thing",
  "link": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/build3-9b01e.appspot.com/o/24845784_1498412240196703_2260522595910680576_n.jpg?alt=media&token=a10bf237-1716-4bfa-aac2-3a9abb9bb6c9",
  "userId": "riazosama"
},
"05": {
  "description": "Best Thing",
  "link": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/build3-9b01e.appspot.com/o/24845421_322450898237800_880491097661374464_n.jpg?alt=media&token=d06f1640-8e1f-4b1c-b6c5-8a39854cc474",
  "userId": "riazosama"
},
"06": {
  "description": "Best Thing",
  "link": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/build3-9b01e.appspot.com/o/24845144_2065724523649789_5632988310377857024_n.jpg?alt=media&token=f8dd5d1c-94f6-47bf-89c4-36866f5be0b5",
  "userId": "riazosama"
},
"07": {
  "description": "Best Thing",
  "link": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/build3-9b01e.appspot.com/o/24327898_163605550912688_741693478529925120_n.jpg?alt=media&token=bd8b47bd-94fa-4bfd-955b-ab7982947d1f",
  "userId": "riazosama"
}
 },
"User": {
"riazosama": {
  "name": "Osama Riaz",
  "email": "riazosama@gmail.com",
  "password": "1122"
},
"arsamriazz": {
  "name": "Arsam Riaz",
  "email": "arsamriaz@gmail.com",
  "password": "1122"
}
}
}
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve all the images from "Images" Table where 'UserId' matches to my desired Id. Let's just say for this example, where UserId matches "arsamriazz".

This is the code I'm trying to retrive images with. It's not displaying anything.

```
    if(getIntent() != null){
        userId = getIntent().getStringExtra("UserId");
        Log.e("ID", userId);
    }
    if(!userId.isEmpty()){
        loadimages();
    }



     private void loadimages() {
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Images, UserImagesViewHolder>(Images.class, R.layout.activity_user_profile_images,
            UserImagesViewHolder.class,
            table_images.orderByChild("UserId").equalTo(userId)) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UserImagesViewHolder viewHolder, Images model, int position) {
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getLink())
                    .into(viewHolder.posted_img);
        }
    };
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //referesh if data is changend
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: can you print the link before you load it?

Comment: @tamtom i can load the images when i only use this:

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Images, UserImagesViewHolder>(Images.class, R.layout.activity_user_profile_images,
            UserImagesViewHolder.class,
            table_images.

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've edited the question.

Comment: In your code you have `orderByChild("UserId")` with a uppercase `U`. In your JSON it's `"userId"` with a lowercase `u`. Firebase is case-sensitive, so the two will need to match.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You are the best. Such a stupid mistake I did there. Thanks alot.